# Do offline ARM cores in Linux still consume power?

Tags: linux, arm, offline

In Fedora24 if a ARM core is set to offline, is it still consuming power?  e.g. running at lowest clock (400MHz) but not scheduled for any tasks by the kernel?  Or is the core actually powered off or in a deep sleep state?

My current measurements of a quad core ARM do not indicate any decrease when cores 1,2,3 are set to offline.

```
echo "0" > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/online
echo "0" > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu2/online
echo "0" > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu3/online

cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/online   < returns 0 >
```

Comment: it depends on whether it is in reset or not as to how much power it consumes, but yes it will still consume some.  Note, sometimes reset consumes more than idling, depends on the design and implementation.  You can try using WFI or other state built into the core, or if possible you can try starving the clock if there is a clock enable (the core has these but the chip vendor has to implement access to them or not) or a reset or both.

Comment: and of course depends on the linux port as to what this high level online/offline setting does.

Comment: can guarantee with 99.99999% comfort that it is not powered off, not if a multic-core processor. (unless they are completely separate cores and not one ip blob with multiple cores).  of course saying that will invite folks to prove me wrong or find that one use case...

Comment: Thanks for this info.  Initially I have all 4 cores online and dynamically take cores 1/2/3 offline, so I do not think they are reverting to the reset state.   I will need to investigate this Linux port to see how online/offline is handled.

Comment: they could be or could not depends on design/implemenatation, they could simply be sitting in a tight loop running from cache or most likely sitting in wfi instruction or perhaps even have interrupts happening and are simply cleared and discarded.  any one of these would work technically and functionally.  (well some chips may not have individual reset controls and the cores are either all out of reset or not, but individually you can use wfi or a breakpoint perhaps)

Comment: A lot if not most of the power consumption comes from gates switching states, so clocking is the first problem then how many gates are being clocked and of those how many are changing states and how often.  so even idling in a small loop should cause less power consumption than actively running through code, so yes assuming those terms mean something, I would expect putting some cores into that software or other state would reduce power consumption.

Comment: OK - thanks.   Looking at documentation for the ARM Cortex A-9 they offer 4 states (section 5.3.1 in document: DDI0407I_cortex_a9_mpcore_r4p1_trm.pdf)

**Run** - Everything is clocked and powered up.
**Standby** - CPU clock stopped, only logic required for wake-up is active
**Dormant** - Everything is powered off except RAM arrays in retention mode
**Shutdown** - Everything is powered off      I need to map these to the online/offline of the CPU policies.

Comment: I would have a hard time with "powered" off, clock gated and/or in reset perhaps, but power controls are not something you get in verilog from arm.  Id have to look at that, but anyway you are on the right path to find out how low of a power mode you are in or can get into if the linux port is not already doing it.

Answer (score 0):

It is still consuming power because you set it on a clock speed that is more than zero.